# How to read Lines of text from a file into a 2D matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I want to read a text file that contains the following:

```
--------------------
---+---+---+--+-----
-------------+------
++-----------+------
-+-+----+------+----
--------------------
-----------+-------+
------+----+-------+
+-------------------
--+--------+------+-
```

I want to not only split this data into separate lines, but I want to split it into separate characters as well. For example, I want the data to read into the matrix as follows:

[
['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
['-','-','-','+','-','-','-','+','-','-','-','+''-','-','+','-','-','-','-','-',],
...
]
This would end up being a 10 by 20 matrix

I am willing and able to use any libraries at my disposal.

I have tried looping through the file after reading it, and making a list of characters, and storing the list of characters into a parent list, but this just makes a list of a list, but I want to make a list of many lists (in this case, a list of 10 rows with 20 columns (or characters) in each list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    print([[y for y in x[:-1]] for x in f.readlines()])
```

It will create a list of many lists, the x[:-1] is to escape the "\n" at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `list` inside a list comprehension to convert each line to a list.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    grid = [list(line.strip()) for line in f]
```